# Remove folders from HDFS from command line

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am looking to remove folders and files for my hive user.

```
hadoop fs -rm -R -f -skipTrash /user/hive/warehouse/storage_20160315
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#rm

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways of doing this is as below:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /user/hive/warehouse/storage_20160315
```

This will remove the content of storage_20160315 a well as the directory itself.

Or you can use HUE interface as well

Comment: Hi @townie ,glad it worked, if you found the answer helpful, please except it as i could help others in future as well.